# Unauthorized Access When Moving a File, But the Account I'm Impersonating Has Permission?

Tags: c#, windows, file, permissions

On my MVC website, there is a page that archives an old file and writes a new one.

However, when I archive the old file, I get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was caught
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access to the path is denied.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
       at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
       at Controller.Action in C:\Program\Controllers\MyController.cs:line 201
  InnerException:
```

I've checked the permissions on the account that I'm impersonating, and the account has Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, Read, and Write permissions on the folder I'm trying to write to.

Maybe I'm missing something about the file permissions? The error is when I'm trying to move the file into the archive on \server123\D$\Archive. I know that when I archive the file at C:\Temp\Archive (my machine), the program works perfectly. I am also able to write a new file without any trouble to \server123\Test. Could the error be because I'm moving from one drive of the server to another? If that is the case... is there a way around it so I can write from \server123\Test to \server123\D$\Archive?

Here is the code I'm using to move the file.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult MoveFile(MoveFileViewModel model)
{
    string cartonsXml = GetCartonsXml(model);

    try
    {
        //Impersonate user who has access to both folders.
        string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUser"].ToString();
        string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileDomain"].ToString();
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePassword"].ToString();

        ImpersonateUser impersonateUser = new ImpersonateUser();
        IntPtr token = impersonateUser.GetUserToken(user, domain, password);

        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            using (WindowsImpersonationContext wic = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token))
            {
                //Move old cartons.xml file to archive.
                string oldCartonsFilePath = Path.Combine(@"\\server123\Test", "cartons.xml");
                string archiveFilePath = Path.Combine(@"\\server123\D$\Archive", "cartons("
                    + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + ")." + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml");

                System.IO.File.Move(oldCartonsFilePath, archiveFilePath); //This is where I catch the exception!

                //Write new cartons.xml file.
                string newCartonsFilePath = Path.Combine(@"\\server123\Test", "cartons.xml");

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newCartonsFilePath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(cartonsXml);
                    sw.Close();
                }

                ViewBag.MsgText = "Complete!";
                ViewBag.MsgColor = "Green";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.MsgText = "Credentials failed! Files not moved!";
            ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.MsgText = ex.Message;
        ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Please help! :(

Comment: rename / move is copy old file to new file and then delete the old file. So you need full control on the original folder (contents) and write on the new.

Comment: Let me check this right now. I'll put full control onto the account I'm impersonating.

Comment: The scary bit id full control is more than delete, might want to have play around with the advanced button. Don't know enough about it to help myself.

Comment: I put full control on both folders, but I am receiving the same error.

Comment: Did you cascade the permission changes to the files already in the folder?

Comment: Rather than flailing around in the dark, I'd suggest using Process Monitor (on TechNet) to see exactly what's going on. Set a filter on the file Path you're interested in and see what happens when you run the code. You should see an event for the file operation with an Access Denied result which you can open to view more information.  For example, it might be that your impersonation isn't working as expected, or maybe path mappings are getting messed up.

Comment: Another possibility is that another process has the file open.

Comment: Side note: your sample shows bad practice of saving XML - please consider updating it to be just generic string. Also you don't need `.Close` if you are using `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a variety of trials and errors, I created a share of the folder I'm trying to access, granted the account I'm using read/write permissions to it, and now the code works correctly. I will be updating my code based on the comments I've seen here. Thanks guys!